# Как реализовать создание потока

Tags: java, android-studio

мне нужен поток который будет выполнять вот эту функцию

```
public void onclick(View view){

        if (REG1 >=100000)
        {
            REG1 = 10;


        }
        //System.out.println(REG1 + " " + REG1);
        REG1 = REG1+REG1;

        N1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.N1);
        N1.setText("" + REG1);

}
```

Comment: что вы понимаете под потоком?

Comment: threads с runnable или outputstream, я ещё не сильно разобрался,но мне нужно то что будет независимо выполнять действие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо вам нужен `Handler`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      while(true){
        if (REG1 >=100000) {
           REG1 = 10;
        }
        //System.out.println(REG1 + " " + REG1);
        REG1 = REG1+REG1;

        N1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.N1);
        N1.setText("" + REG1);
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку он должен начинать крутить счётчик, чтобы он циклично повторял это место независимо от остального кода который идёт построчно

Comment: И как это было понятно из вашего вопроса?

Comment: ну вообще это другой поток, там вы можете цикл написать

Comment: К сожалению не как

Comment: видимо как-то так

Comment: Как называется "другой поток" где я ещё цикл могу писать

Comment: может `Thread`?